# Question about storing data in arrays in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So right now I am currently storing data with a number after it like EmailSubject1, EmailSubject2, etc which obviously is a stupid way of doing things.

I would instead like to store these in arrays like EmailSubject[1], EmailSubject[2] etc.

I spent some time looking over the firebase documentation and searching online but was struggling to find a solution and I am unfamilar in storing things in firebase this way personally.

```
   let z = 0;
              for (z = 0; z < 20; z++) {
                db.collection("Users")
                  .doc("6IzsLbD4r4R5RXdGB5BQy6xq8Dc2")
                  .set(
                    {
                      ["EmailSubject" + z]: mail.subject,
                      ["EmailBody" + z]: mail.text,
                      ["EmailFrom" + z]: mail.from,
                      ["EmailDate" + z]: newDate,
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                  )

                  .then(() => {
                    console.log("Doc successful");

                    return null;
                  })

                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing doc", error);
                  });
              }
```

Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated =]

Comment: Can you show the document/fields structure you are exactly looking for?

Comment: Probably to have 1 main EmailSubject, EmailBody, EmailFrom, EmailDate. And then inside of each of those, EmailSubject[1], EmailSubject[2] etc as it loops and keeps adding the data. Does that make sense? I am storing many emails and these are things I am storing from them. @RenaudTarnec Then I will know EmailSubject[1] and EmailFrom[1] go together.

Comment: See the answer. Note that Array's index starts at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can use [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to add elements to the different arrays, but you should note that this method **will only add elements that are not already present**.

So if you are sure that you only add new data, you could do as follows:

```
  var promises = [];
  var docRef = db
    .collection('Users')
    .doc('6IzsLbD4r4R5RXdGB5BQy6xq8Dc2');

  for (z = 0; z < 20; z++) {
    promises.push(
      docRef.set(
        {
          EmailSubject: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
            mail.subject + z
          ),
          EmailBody: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('text' + z),
          //....
        },
        { merge: true }
      )
    );
  }
  Promise.all(promises);
```

---

If, on the opposite, there are values that are similar in one of the Arrays, you would need to read the Array in your client, push the new value and write back the entire Array.

Ex.: If your `EmailFrom` array is `['john@gmail.com', 'jack@gmail.com', 'john@gmail.com']`, `arrayUnion()` will not work.